# Making sequential strings in c programming

Tags: c

I am trying to create a list of possible passwords and wanted to know how to go about making a for loop (or several) so that I can make sequential passwords. For example, one password would be `aa0aa`, next would be `aa0ab`, etc. 
The password requirements are that it's only 5 characters long, the first two characters are lowercase letters followed by a number and then followed by two more lowercase letters. In the end, I'll be writing these strings either to the console or to a file (I can do this part, but I am not exactly sure how I could change the string from one instance to the next).

I am not asking anyone to do this for me, only asking for a little push in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You know you can have loops inside of other loops? You also know that a character is just a number representing the character in a specific character set? And that on most PC-like systems the common character set is [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) where all letters are consecutive and so are the numbers, which means that it's easy to loop over characters from `'a'` to `'z'`? And if you have an array, you can easily modify just a single element in that array? And lastly, you do  know that all strings have an extra character at the end telling the end of the string?

Comment: Put together all the information in my comment above, and you have *a* solution.

Comment: you could make an array of possible characters, array holding a set of positions `{0,0,0,0,0}`, then go through a while loop, incrementing value at the zero index (to `{1,0,0,0,0}`), and so on until you reach length of your characters list, then set it again to zero and increment the next one (you will have to loop though other positions to make sure you do not overflow your array of chars). Then always print a set of chars given by positions. You can of course add some rules (which chars to skip at given positions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it for a two-character password:

```
char password[3];
password[sizeof password - 1] = '\0';
for (password[0] = 'a'; password[0] <= 'z'; ++password[0]) {
    for (password[1] = 'a'; password[1] <= 'z'; ++password[1]) {
        printf("%s\n", password);
    }
}
```

This hint should point you in the right direction.

Note: not a Unicode-compliant solution.